# Change URL before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="/create_test1/54ae2be44a1bfef3138b4569">
.
.
.
<input type="button" id="export" value="Export">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#export").click(function(){
  url = $("#form").attr("action");
  url = url.replace("create_test1","export_test1"); // This is OK
  $('#form').attr('action', url).submit();  //Here form is not submited
});
```

**Actual URL** : /create_test1/54ae2be44a1bfef3138b4569

**I want URL** : /export_test1/54ae2be44a1bfef3138b4569

My Question is How to submit form after changing action?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xu3gLw2g/

Comment: In jsFiddle working fine but in my case form do not POST.

Comment: I tried it locally too and works perfectly.

Comment: Are you getting some error or is your form still getting submitted to the old url?

Comment: I have two button for single form `Submit` and `Export` when click on `Submit` it will post form through ajax and when click on `Export` it will export excel.

Comment: @AlokRanjan No any error but do not post form

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#export").click(function()
{
 $('#form').attr('action', '/export_test1/54ae2be44a1bfef3138b4569'); 
});
```

Comment: My expected url `/export_test1/54ae2be44a1bfef3138b4569`